# Where is the roadmap for EOS development? What is happing in 2019 and beyond?

Tags: mainnet, development, block.one

What is planned for EOS in the coming future? Where can one see the roadmap for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOS is a decentralized public blockchain managed by a community. There are many independent roadmaps from various projects that may be building privacy-focused side chains, tooling for developers, governance/ecosystem tools, decentralized exchanges, and others.

Further, EOS blockchain uses the EOSIO software, which was developed and is primarily maintained by Block.one. The vast majority of protocol-level work is performed by the Block.one team who released [a public roadmap](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/Roadmap.md), but it is unfortunately not updated regularly, followed closely, nor does it mention 2019 plans. However, from public communication from various Block.one officials, it appears that some of the next steps for `eosio` are focused on:

- **Scaling via sidechains**, which requires finalizing the inter-blockchain communication (IBC) implementation;
- **Asynchronous Byzantine fault tolerant (aBFT)** which improves irreversibility times by allowing BPs to communicate commitments directly to each other instead of inferring them implicitly from block headers;
- **Resource Exchange (REX)** for allowing token leasing and encouraging voting participation;
- Launching and promoting **dApps** sponsored by EOS VC or created by Block.one developers. Here, one of the better known announcements is a Block.one developed decentralized social network dubbed as Steemit 2.0, referencing one of Dan's previous projects;
- Creating infrastructure for the **4% inflation** which may include Universal Resource Inheritance (URI) as proposed by Dan, Worker Proposal System (WPS) as suggested in the whitepaper, or other mechanism.

Note, however, that none of these have been committed to with a release date or a clear roadmap, and Block.one's work may include significant work that is not relevant to EOS public chains (i.e. work on private chains for corporations)